# How to make nav bar active when it is clicked in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code of nav bar

```
<div id="sidebar"><a href="" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon icon-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>


<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/admin/dashboard') }}"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
<li class="submenu"> <a href=""><i class="icon icon-th-large"></i> <span>Menu</span> </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/admin/add-menu') }}">Add Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/admin/view-menu') }}">View All Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How to make menu active when it is clicked? In my project, dashboard is always active..

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li {{ Request::url() === 'admin/dashboard' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="{{ url('admin/dashboard') }}"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
    <li class="submenu"> <a href=""><i class="icon icon-th-large"></i> <span>Menu</span> </a>
        <ul>
            <li {{ Request::url() === 'admin/add-menu' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="{{ url('/admin/add-menu') }}">Add Menu</a></li>
            <li {{ Request::url() === 'admin/view-menu' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="{{ url('/admin/add-menu') }}"><a href="{{ url('/admin/view-menu') }}">View All Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

if this does not work then you might be having named routes. you need to replace for example 'admin/dashboard' with your name of the route

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the nav bar active by checking the current url.

Suppose your url is "/admin/dashboard", then you can add this check :

```
@if (\Request::is('admin/dashboard'))  
   <li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/admin/dashboard') }}"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
@else
   <li class=""><a href="{{ url('/admin/dashboard') }}"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
@endif
```

In else condition you need to remove the active class, and in if condition you need to add the active class.

Comment: Yes it will work on click itself when it will be clicked then it will get redirected to url which you have defined in href and when url matches with the condition then it will automatically become active.

Comment: It was my mistake try @if (\Request::is('admin/dashboard')) it should work i have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

So you can use:

```
Request::is()
```

Try this

```
<ul>
<li{{ (Request::is('admin/dashboard') || Request::is('/admin/dashboard')) ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="{{ url('/admin/dashboard') }}"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
<li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th-large"></i> <span>Menu</span> </a>
  <ul>
    <li{{ (Request::is('admin/add-menu') || Request::is('/admin/add-menu')) ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="{{ url('/admin/add-menu') }}">Add Menu</a></li>
    <li{{ (Request::is('admin/view-menu') || Request::is('/admin/view-menu')) ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="{{ url('/admin/view-menu') }}">View All Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```